# Custom Animation (Expand/Collapse) from 2 Different Inputs

Tags: android, android-animation, adapter, android-cardview

I am new Android Developer and I am making an **App** which stores some **expiration dates** and displays them on the MainActivity.

On the **SelectionActivity** I have a custom Adapter to display some **EditTexts** and 2 **Buttons**. I have **onClick ANIMATION** to Expand/Collapse accordingly for the **View**.

**The problem:** Since I am using the inside buttons to store and pass the data to another activity, i need to also be able to Expand/Collapse the corresponding view **on click**. How can I achieve this?

[image: SelectionActivity]

I have tried using the same Collapse animation inside the **onBindViewHelper** but it does mediocre the job, only hiding the constraint layout and not reducing its height size.

If you have any feedback or need any other activity, dont hesitate to indulge me!

**FormAdapter**

```
public class FormAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FormAdapter.ViewHolder> {

public static final String FORM_PREFERENCES = "FormPreferences";
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Document> mDocuments;

public FormAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Document> mDocuments) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mDocuments = mDocuments;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.format_form, parent, false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Document document = mDocuments.get(position);
    holder.mTitle.setText(document.getName());
    holder.mTitleExpanded.setText(document.getName());
    holder.mEditText.setTag(R.id.date_et, position);
    holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            int position = (int) holder.mEditText.getTag(R.id.date_et);
            Log.d("pos", String.valueOf(position));

            SharedPreferences mSP = v.getContext().getSharedPreferences(FORM_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = mSP.edit();

            String data = holder.mEditText.getText().toString();

            switch (position){
                case 0:

                    Log.d("SOAT", data);
                    mEditor.putString("soat", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 1:

                    Log.d("RTM", data);
                    mEditor.putString("rtm", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 2:

                    Log.d("SRC", data);
                    mEditor.putString("src", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 3:

                    Log.d("STR", data);
                    mEditor.putString("str", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
                case 4:

                    Log.d("TO", data);
                    mEditor.putString("to", data);
                    mEditor.commit();

                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mDocuments != null ? mDocuments.size(): 0;
}


public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{

    public TextView mTitle, mTitleExpanded;
    public Button mButton;
    public EditText mEditText;
    public ImageView mImageView;

    public int originalHeight = 0;
    public boolean isViewExpanded = false;
    public ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout;
    private DateWatcher mDateWatcher;

    public ViewHolder(final View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);

        mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.expanded);
        mTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_title_tv);
        mTitleExpanded = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_title_tv_expanded);
        mButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.add_button);
        mEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.date_et);
        mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView_up);

        mDateWatcher = new DateWatcher(mEditText);
        mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mDateWatcher);


        if (isViewExpanded == false) {
            // Set Views to View.GONE and .setEnabled(false)
            mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        // If the originalHeight is 0 then find the height of the View being used
        // This would be the height of the ConstraintLayout
        if (originalHeight == 0) {
            originalHeight = v.getHeight();
        }

        // Declare a ValueAnimator object
        ValueAnimator valueAnimator;
        if (!isViewExpanded) {
            mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mTitle.setEnabled(false);
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(true);
            isViewExpanded = true;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight, originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight)); // These values in this method can be changed to expand however much you like
        } else {
            isViewExpanded = false;
            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(originalHeight + (int) (originalHeight), originalHeight);

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

            a.setDuration(200);
            // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    mTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mTitle.setEnabled(true);
                    mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            // Set the animation on the custom view
            mConstraintLayout.startAnimation(a);
        }
        valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
        valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                v.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        });
        valueAnimator.start();

    }
}
}
```

**FormActivity.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/card_view_form"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:layout_margin="5dp">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name_title_tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:text="Revisión Técnico Mecánica"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_up"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:rotation="180"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_black_down"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/name_title_tv"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"/>

    <include layout="@layout/format_form_expanded"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**FormActivity**

```
public class Form extends AppCompatActivity {

private DBHelper mDBHelper;
private Context mContext;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<Document> mArrayList;
private FormAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

    mDBHelper = new DBHelper(this);

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.hint);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
    //for dismissing anywhere you touch
    View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.hint);
    masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_form);

    mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_soat, 0));
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_rtm, 1));
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_src, 2));
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_str, 3));
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_tao, 4));
    mArrayList.add(new Document(R.string.doc_ext, 5));
    mAdapter = new FormAdapter(mContext, mArrayList);

    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### After some digging and walkthrough of the whole logic, i came with this boilerplate answer:

- You need to declare the Viewgroup in the **ViewHolder** to receive it in the **onBindViewHolder**
- Pass it to the needed height
- You **MUST** be clear in the View **animationUpdateListener**

Like these you get the **onClick animation for the View and the Button**

```
    holder.mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            if (holder.originalHeight == 0) {
                holder.originalHeight = holder.mCardView.getHeight();
            }

            holder.isViewExpanded = false;
            ValueAnimator valueAnimator;

            valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(holder.originalHeight + (int) (holder.originalHeight), holder.originalHeight);

            Animation a = new AlphaAnimation(1.00f, 0.00f); // Fade out

            a.setDuration(200);
            // Set a listener to the animation and configure onAnimationEnd
            a.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    holder.mConstraintLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    holder.mConstraintLayout.setEnabled(false);
                    holder. mTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    holder.mTitle.setEnabled(true);
                    holder. mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

                }
            });

            // Set the animation on the custom view
            holder.mConstraintLayout.startAnimation(a);

            valueAnimator.setDuration(200);
            valueAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
            valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
                    holder.mCardView.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
                    holder.mCardView.requestLayout();
                }
            });
            valueAnimator.start();


        }
    });
```